Pandas concat multiples specific columns if value is True
This is my first dataframe.

How can i achieve only concat the columns name with _flag only and concat its value if True to another column at each row. The expected outcome is the dataframe below

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a= dict()
a['name']=['test','test1']
a['a_flag']=[True,True]
a['b_flag']=[True,False]
a['c_flag']=[True,False]
a['d_flag']=[True,True]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
col_flag = df.filter(like='_flag')


Does this answer your question? For each row, add column name to list in new column if row value matches a condition

You can use a simple loop and numpy boolean indexing:
df['checking'] = [','.join(col_flag.columns[a]) for a in col_flag.to_numpy()]

Or with a hacky dot product:
df['checking'] = (col_flag@(col_flag.columns+',')).str[:-1]

Output:
    name  a_flag  b_flag  c_flag  d_flag                     checking
0   test    True    True    True    True  a_flag,b_flag,c_flag,d_flag
1  test1    True   False   False    True                a_flag,d_flag

Intermediates for the boolean indexing:
# col_flag.to_numpy()
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True]])

# ','.join(col_flag.columns[a])  # assuming the second row
# a = [ True, False, False,  True]
# col_flag.columns[a]
Index(['a_flag', 'd_flag'], dtype='object')

# ','.join(col_flag.columns[a])
'a_flag,d_flag'

The dot product works by adding a , suffix, transforming the False string to empty string with matrix multiplication, then combining the strings to a single string with addition. Finally, we remove the extra ,.
timings
The dot product is much more efficient if you have a lot or rows and just a few columns. For instance for 200k rows and 4 columns:
# loop
1.29 s ± 23.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# dot product
72.7 ms ± 1.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

But it is slower if you have many columns. For example 2 rows, 40k columns:
# loop
6.24 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# dot product
254 ms ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


what is the logic here? how it can detect the True value only

@Clarence we convert to numpy array to be able to loop over the rows, then for each (boolean) row, we use it to select the True column names. I updated the answer with details

oh the col_flag.columns[a] will auto return the True columns?

Yes, this is called boolean indexing

thanks i learned new thing today. Have a nice day !!

You're welcome, glad it solved your issue
